# Using 1 (insert) button, can I insert multiple row data from an HTML table to a MySQL database table?

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I have randomly generated questions and decided to put those in a temporary table. Now, it is already in my html table:

```
echo "<form action=# method=post>";
echo "<table>";
do{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>"."<input type=text value='$rows[question]' name=question>"."</td>;
echo "<td>"."<input type=text value='$rows[correct]' name=correct>"."</td>;
}while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($rs));
echo "</table>";


echo "<input type=submit name=insert>";

echo "</form>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

What I want to happen is, when I hit the insert button name="insert", data from that table, [from row 1 till the last row] will be inserted to my database "tbl_randomq". Is it possible to insert multiple row data simultaneously to database with just 1 click.

I've tried to use  while loop, but it only inserts repeated(10times) data coming from the last row. Help with this please :-)

Comment: You can save table data in an array and use them whenever you want. That's the best way.

Comment: Sir @Sky, will you show it please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
do{
?>
<tr>
    <td><input type=text value='<?=$row["question"]?>' name='question[]'></td>
    <td><input type=text value='<?=$row["correct"]?>' name='correct[]'></td>    
</tr>
<?php
}while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs));
```

Then to save this :

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($_POST['question']); $i++){
    $question = addslashes($_POST['question'][$i]);
    $correct = addslashes($_POST['correct'][$i]);
    mysqli_query("
                      insert into tbl_ramdomq (question, correct) 
                      values ('$question','$correct')
    "); 
}
```

Replace code formatting with your own as you wish. Though for myself I prefer to use short php tags inside html rather than `echo` because of syntax coloring and better clarity.

Comment: Thank you sir! I will try your answer. Will it be like, from my database:tbl_question TO html form table then TO database:tbl_randomq?

Comment: I'm not sure how you did your data structure, but here you have 'question' and 'correct' in the loop, so do whatever you need to with them. If you need to pass an `id`, you can add it in your form as an hidden field.

Comment: Okay sir! Thanks! That for loop would be placed after my insert query, right? Thank you very much sir! GodBless you :-)

Comment: No, you should place your insert query INTO the loop.
So you can insert the values of `$question` and `$correct` which change at everyloop to whatever values they had in the table. see?

Comment: $sql2="insert into tbl_ramdomq (question, correct) values ('$_POST[question]','$_POST[correct]');"

Comment: Sir, can you edit the for loop code part and kindly insert my query so I could understand it better?  please.

Comment: There it is. I didn't test though, let me know.